# AWS Glue job logs stream to include custom prefix with Job ID and Date

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using Glue 4.0 and the logs getting generated just include the jobid. Now I want the log stream to include details such as custom prefix, job id and date. This will help me to identify the job which is generating the log along with the date in which it got generated.

I tried using '--continuous-log-logStreamPrefix': 'custom_log_stream_prefix' but this just replaces the job id with the custom prefix. I would want the job id as well.